# Use Association or List attribute in UML Class diagram?

Tags: attributes, uml, class-diagram, model-associations

I have identified two classes that I want to implement in code like this:

```
InsuranceProviders{ 
}

Advice{
    List<InsuranceProviders> providers;
}
```

If I wanted to represent these two classes in a UML class diagram, should the `Advice` class have an Association with `InsuranceProvider`, or should it have a list attribute of `InsuranceProvider` instead?

[With Association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2LRS.jpg)

[With Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up8gi.jpg)

Or maybe something else?

Comment: See also this blog post: https://bellekens.com/tag/association/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless it's a simple value attribute, like a number or a string, always use an association.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: A list is equivalent to an association end property, and an association makes it clear that two identifiable things are related.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose. Both options are valid in UML. I would prefer the association, though, because in that case, the relationship between the two classes is more prominently visualized.

By the way, in your diagram 'With Association', you should position the text "+providers" near the InsuranceProvider class, not in the middle of the line.

In your diagram "With Attribute", you should notate the attribute as follows:

`+providers: InsuranceProvider[0..*]`